# Action Text (Trix) styles doesn't load in production (Rails 6, Heroku)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, tailwind-css, actiontext

For some reason I'm struggling with making Action Text (Trix editor) icons bar to load in production (Heroku).
I'm building a relatively simple web app using Rails 6 & TailwindCSS.
Action Text is fully functional both locally and in production, but while styles are loaded as expected on my local machine, I'm unable to make it work in production.

**localhost:**
[image: localhost]
**production:**
[image: production]

**app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import 'trix/dist/trix.css';
@import "components/actiontext";

/*! purgecss start ignore */
@import "components/buttons";
@import "components/forms";
/*! purgecss end ignore */
```

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")

import "stylesheets/application"
import "controllers"
```

**app/javascript/stylesheets/components/actiontext.scss**

```
@import "trix/dist/trix.css";

// trix-toolbar {
//   .trix-button {
//     @apply bg-white border-0;
//   }

//   .trix-button-group {
//     border: 0;
//   }

//   .trix-button--icon-bold {
//     @apply rounded-tl rounded-bl;
//   }

//   .trix-button--icon-redo {
//     @apply rounded-tr rounded-br;
//   }
// }

// .trix-button--icon-attach,
// .trix-button-group-spacer,
// .trix-button--icon-decrease-nesting-level,
// .trix-button--icon-increase-nesting-level,
// .trix-button--icon-code {
//   display: none;
// }

.trix-button-group--file-tools { display: none !important; }

.trix-content {
  .attachment-gallery {
    > action-text-attachment,
    > .attachment {
      flex: 1 0 33%;
      padding: 0 0.5em;
      max-width: 33%;
    }

    &.attachment-gallery--2,
    &.attachment-gallery--4 {
      > action-text-attachment,
      > .attachment {
        flex-basis: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
      }
    }
  }

  action-text-attachment {
    .attachment {
      padding: 0 !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}
```

**app/views/shared/_head.html.erb (relevant part)**

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag  'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag  'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

**UPDATE:**
I have followed Elrik's advice and excluded Trix & actiontext.scss from PurgeCSS. Now it's better, but still something is off:
[image]

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any failure or warning output from asset compilation when pushing to Heroku?

Comment: Nothing :( no failures of any kind.

Comment: Did you solve it in the meantime? Confronted with the same issue!

Answer (score 7):

In that case the `node_modules/trix/dist/trix.css` doesn't load properly. I had it too and I solved it the following way:

Make sure you have the exact same setup as described in the [Rails Action Text Documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#installation). I too used the rails installer with `rails action_text:install`, but that seems to implement a slightly different installation as described in the documentation (maybe differing depending on your webpacker / sprockets setup - don't know)

---

**Extract from the named Rails documentation:**

Both trix and @rails/actiontext should be required in your JavaScript pack.

```
// application.js
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
```

The trix stylesheet should be imported into actiontext.scss.

```
@import "trix/dist/trix";
```

Additionally, this actiontext.scss file should be imported into your stylesheet pack.

```
// application.scss
@import "./actiontext.scss";
```

Comment: In addition to the above, in my Rails 7 app, actiontext css was installed as "actiontext.css", not "actiontext.scss". I had to rename the file "actiontext.scss" and then referenced it in application.scss as @import 'actiontext';  -- now everything loads perfectly on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell purgecss to ignore purging trix. Since trix classes is loaded through js on the `form.rich_text_area` , it doesn't find the classes in your files.

Quick solution is to add this to your application.scss in your javascript/stylesheets folder

```
/*! purgecss start ignore */
@import "trix/dist/trix";
/*! purgecss end ignore */
```

This tells the purgecss to not purge trix classes when it compiles.

You can also add trix classes to your whitelite to see if that helps

in your postcss.config.js add

```
whitelistPatterns: [/trix-*/],
```

I had the same issue as you and my first solutions solved it.

```
if (process.env.RAILS_ENV === "production") {
  environment.plugins.push(
    require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')({
      content: [
        './app/**/*.html.erb',
        './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
        './app/components/**/*.rb',
        './app/javascript/**/*.js',
        
      ],
      whitelistPatterns: [/trix-*/],
      defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[A-Za-z0-9-_:/]+/g) || []
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that is definitely a step in the right direction, but sadly I'm not there yet. even after ignoring trix & actiontext.scss, icons styling is better but still off :( I've updated the issue with the appropriate screenshot from production.